# RESTful login using ajax and node.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, node.js

I'm struggling with a rather simple approach to login to a server and later on to ensure that I'm still logged in, I'm sending a GET request to receive my user name. I'm using a little node.js server and a single page object using JQuery.

```
//  prints User name to the console if logged in
function getUserName() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:4730/login",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (resJson) {
            $.each(resJson, function (i, userName) {
                console.log(userName);
            });
        },
        error: function (xhr, status) {
            console.log("Sorry, there was a problem!");
        }
    });
}

//  login a known user
function login(name, password) {
    var userData = {
        name: name,
        password: password
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:4730/login",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: userData,
        error: function (xhr, status) {
            console.log("Sorry, there was a problem!");
        },
        complete: function (xhr, status) {
            console.log(xhr);
        }
    });
}
```

My server (node.js) is generating a dummy user id and checks this one when the next GET request arrives.

```
// Checks if the user is logged in and returns its name or an empty string
app.get('/login', function (req, res) {
    if (typeof (req.session.user_id) == "number") {
        res.json(users[req.session.user_id].name);
        return;
    }
    res.json("");
});

// Check if the user exists and if the password is correct
app.post('/login', function (req, res) {
var post = req.body;  
var user = findUser(post.name);  
if( !!user && post.password == user.password)
    {       
        req.session.user_id = user.id;      
        res.json(true);     
        return;
    }   
    res.json(false);
});
```

My user is already registered and the login request returns successfully. But after logged in, my GET request to getUserName returns an empty string. What I don't get is where is the session.user_id set? Doesn't the client has to now it?

I have already seen couple of solutions by using passport, etc but I would like to understand the basic of the session/user id handling.

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
var post = req.body;   // the request body with username & password.
var user = findUser(post.name);  // you are extracting the username 
if( !!user && post.password == user.password)
  //---------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^-----this isn't available in it.
```

---

1. In your `var post` you have all the posted request body, which has name & password.
2. In your `var user` you are extracting the name out of posted values.
3. Now in your `if` condition i don't think `user.password` is available.

Either make sure you would return the object from `findUser(post.name)` or change it to: `post.password != ""`

Comment: Hi Jai, thanks a lot for your reply. I should have mentioned, that my user is already registered and the comparison of the password is successfull. It seems to me, that my client doesn't now its user id, which is assigned here: `req.session.user_id = user.id;` Thanks again.